# Get index first and last same item in ArrayList?

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, arraylist, foreach

I have a model :

```
public class Unprocessed_DistanceTime_D {
    private String lat;
    private String lng;
    private String date;
    private String time;
    private String counts;
    private String userCode;

    public String getLat() {
        return lat;
    }

    public void setLat(String lat) {
        this.lat = lat;
    }

    public String getLng() {
        return lng;
    }

    public void setLng(String lng) {
        this.lng = lng;
    }

    public String getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(String date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public String getTime() {
        return time;
    }

    public void setTime(String time) {
        this.time = time;
    }

    public String getCounts() {
        return counts;
    }

    public void setCounts(String counts) {
        this.counts = counts;
    }

    public String getUserCode() {
        return userCode;
    }

    public void setUserCode(String userCode) {
        this.userCode = userCode;
    }
}
```

And I fill my model with bellow data :

```
     DATE      TIME       LAT            LNG         COUNT 
1395/04/26    12:13:44    34.6117392    50.8548033    7
1395/04/26    12:13:49    34.6117392    50.8548033    7
1395/04/26    12:13:58    34.6117392    50.8548033    7
1395/04/26    12:14:00    34.6117392    50.8548033    7
1395/04/26    12:14:22    34.6117392    50.8548033    7
1395/04/26    12:14:44    34.6117392    50.8548033    7
1395/04/26    12:14:49    34.6117392    50.8548033    7
1395/04/26    12:14:58    34.6113533    50.8551068    27
1395/04/26    12:14:58    34.6113533    50.8551068    27
1395/04/26    12:15:00    34.6113533    50.8551068    27
1395/04/26    12:15:22    34.6113533    50.8551068    27
1395/04/26    12:15:35    34.6322184    50.8596414    9
1395/04/26    12:15:44    34.6113533    50.8551068    27
1395/04/26    12:15:49    34.6113533    50.8551068    27
1395/04/26    12:15:58    34.6113533    50.8551068    27
1395/04/26    12:15:58    34.6113533    50.8551068    27
1395/04/26    12:16:00    34.6113533    50.8551068    27
1395/04/26    12:16:09    34.6322184    50.8596414    9
1395/04/26    12:16:22    34.6113533    50.8551068    27
1395/04/26    12:16:44    34.6113533    50.8551068    27
1395/04/26    12:16:49    34.6113533    50.8551068    27
1395/04/26    12:16:58    34.6113533    50.8551068    27
1395/04/26    12:16:58    34.6113533    50.8551068    27
1395/04/26    12:17:00    34.6113533    50.8551068    27
1395/04/26    12:17:22    34.6113533    50.8551068    27
1395/04/26    12:17:44    34.6113533    50.8551068    27
1395/04/26    12:17:49    34.6113533    50.8551068    27
1395/04/26    12:17:58    34.6113533    50.8551068    27
1395/04/26    12:17:58    34.6113533    50.8551068    27
1395/04/26    12:18:00    34.6113533    50.8551068    27
1395/04/26    12:18:22    34.6113533    50.8551068    27
1395/04/26    12:18:38    34.6322184    50.8596414    9
1395/04/26    12:18:44    34.6113533    50.8551068    27
1395/04/26    12:18:49    34.6113533    50.8551068    27
1395/04/26    12:18:51    34.6322184    50.8596414    9
1395/04/26    12:18:58    34.6113533    50.8551068    27
1395/04/26    12:18:58    34.6113533    50.8551068    27
1395/04/26    12:19:00    34.6113533    50.8551068    27
1395/04/26    12:19:01    34.6113415    50.8562128    22
1395/04/26    12:19:22    34.6113415    50.8562128    22
1395/04/26    12:19:44    34.6113415    50.8562128    22
1395/04/26    12:19:49    34.6113415    50.8562128    22
1395/04/26    12:19:58    34.6113415    50.8562128    22
1395/04/26    12:19:58    34.6113415    50.8562128    22
1395/04/26    12:20:00    34.6113415    50.8562128    22
1395/04/26    12:20:01    34.6113415    50.8562128    22
1395/04/26    12:21:41    34.6322184    50.8596414    9
1395/04/26    12:22:32    34.6113415    50.8562128    22
1395/04/26    12:22:36    34.6322184    50.8596414    9
1395/04/26    12:25:00    34.6113415    50.8562128    22
1395/04/26    12:25:04    34.6113415    50.8562128    22
1395/04/26    12:25:13    34.6113415    50.8562128    22
1395/04/26    12:25:13    34.6113415    50.8562128    22
1395/04/26    12:25:16    34.6113415    50.8562128    22
1395/04/26    12:25:16    34.6113415    50.8562128    22
1395/04/26    12:25:37    34.6113415    50.8562128    22
1395/04/26    12:25:37    34.6322184    50.8596414    9
1395/04/26    12:26:00    34.6113415    50.8562128    22
1395/04/26    12:26:04    34.6113415    50.8562128    22
1395/04/26    12:26:13    34.6113415    50.8562128    22
1395/04/26    12:26:20    34.6113415    50.8562128    22
1395/04/26    12:26:38    34.6113415    50.8562128    22
1395/04/26    12:26:38    34.6322184    50.8596414    9
1395/04/26    12:26:39    34.6113415    50.8562128    22
1395/04/26    12:29:46    34.6322184    50.8596414    9
```

And I write bellow code but don't work for me for get the index of first and last items that are same , I use from you code but I can't get true answer .
My data is sort base time and I don't like change it I should work on this data without change .

My code is here :

```
public class ComputeDetailMoreActivity_E extends AppCompatActivity {
    Context context;

    @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_computedetailmore);
            int count = 1;
            int X = 2;
            boolean flag = true;
            int index1 = -1;
            int index2 = -1;
            Integer counter = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < listCDM.size() - 1; i++) {
                if (listCDM.get(i).getDate().equalsIgnoreCase(listCDM.get(count).getDate()) &&
                        listCDM.get(i).getLat().equalsIgnoreCase(listCDM.get(count).getLat()) &&
                        listCDM.get(i).getLng().equalsIgnoreCase(listCDM.get(count).getLng()) &&
                        listCDM.get(i).getCounts().equalsIgnoreCase(listCDM.get(count).getCounts())) {
                    if (flag) {
                        index1 = i;
                        flag = false;
                        counter++;
                    }
                } else {
                    if (X < listCDM.size()) {
                        if (!listCDM.get(count).getLat().equalsIgnoreCase(listCDM.get(X).getLat()) &&
                                !listCDM.get(count).getLng().equalsIgnoreCase(listCDM.get(X).getLng()) &&
                                !listCDM.get(count).getCounts().equalsIgnoreCase(listCDM.get(X).getCounts())||
                                !listCDM.get(count).getDate().equalsIgnoreCase(listCDM.get(X).getDate())) {

                            Log.i("ADFASFEWRWE", "C : " + listCDM.get(X).getCounts() + "**" +
                                    listCDM.get(X).getTime());
                            index2 = i;
                            Log.i("ASDASRDWE",i + "");
                            int error = count;
                            counter = 2;
                        }
                        if (listCDM.get(count).getLat().equalsIgnoreCase(listCDM.get(X).getLat()) &&
                                listCDM.get(count).getLng().equalsIgnoreCase(listCDM.get(X).getLng()) &&
                                listCDM.get(count).getCounts().equalsIgnoreCase(listCDM.get(X).getCounts()) &&
                                listCDM.get(count).getDate().equalsIgnoreCase(listCDM.get(X).getDate())) {

                            index2 = i;
                            flag = true;
                            counter++;
                        }
                        Log.i("RRTTGGTT", counter + "");
                        if (counter == 2) {
                            Log.i("ASDWERWEDAVVGG", index1 + " : " + index2);
                            flag = true;
                            counter = 0;
                            index1 = -1;
                            index2 = -1;
                        }
                    }
             }
             count++;
              X++;

             }

      }
}
```

My out put is :

```
7 : 6
7 : 10
12 : 16
18 : 30
32 : 33
38 : 45
-1 : 46
-1 : 47
49 : 55
57 : 61
-1 : 62
```

Comment: your question is unclear, please describe what you need

Comment: Please provide the code you have tried so far. SO is not some code giving website. Its rather a problem solving platform

Comment: This seems like a pure Java question and thus the Android tag is not needed here.

Comment: @EJK .I am working in android studio .

Comment: That will not impact the solution in any way.  The code will be the same regardless of the IDE you use.

Comment: Why are you ignoring jim? Also, this is a very basic task. If you're facing a specific problem, spell it out. Otherwise you're just asking us to work for you.

Answer (score 0):

There is an approach that can address you problem...

you will need to use Collections and find how oft the elements appears in the list...

## Example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add("jack");
list.add("jack");
list.add("jack");
list.add("jack");
list.add("jack");
list.add("jim");
list.add("sara");
list.add("sara");
list.add("sara");
list.add("jim");
list.add("ricky");
list.add("ricky");
list.add("ricky");
list.add("angel");
Collections.sort(list);
for (String string : new LinkedHashSet<>(list)) {
    int firstIndex = list.indexOf(string);
    int frequency = Collections.frequency(list, string);
    System.out.println(string + " from: " + firstIndex + " to: " + (firstIndex + frequency - 1));
}
}
```

Comment: .If don't want that the first sort then find I need to find without sort .Thanks a lot if you help me.Then append all of jim names end of list.

Answer (score 0):

For getting the last index you can use HashMap with key as name and value as its index. When entering any name if it exists update its index, otherwise enter that name with value as its index.

For storing the first occurrence use another map, and store in it iff name does not exist in this map.

```
HashMap<String,Integer> firstOccur=new HashMap<String,Integer>();
HashMap<String,Integer> lastOccur=new HashMap<String,Integer>(); 

int index=0;
for(String myList:list){
   if(firstOccur.contains(myList)){
      lastOccur.delete(myList);
      lastOccur.add(myList,index);
   } else{
      firstOccur.add(myList,index);
      lastOccur.add(myList,index);
   }
  index++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Set` as it does not allow duplicates.

Code :

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

list.add("jack");
list.add("jack");
list.add("jack");
list.add("jack");
list.add("jack");
list.add("jim");
list.add("sara");
list.add("sara");
list.add("sara");
list.add("jim");
list.add("ricky");
list.add("ricky");
list.add("ricky");

Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>();

int j = 0;
int k = 0; 
int twoContinuousDifferentValue = 0;
int size = list.size();

for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    String value = list.get(i);
    // set.add returns true if the element does not exists.
    if (set.add(value)) {
        twoContinuousDifferentValue++;
        if (i > 1 && twoContinuousDifferentValue == 1) {
            String currentListvalue = list.get(j);
            System.out.println(currentListvalue + " value starts from index " + j + " And up to index " + (i - k));
        }
        j = i; // storing last new index of second unique value.
    } else {
        twoContinuousDifferentValue = 0;
        if (i + 1 < size) {
            if (value.equalsIgnoreCase(list.get(i + 1))) {
                k = 0;
            } else {
                k += 1; // to count continuous unique values (example sara and jim, as jim was already addded to set, the value of i will increase by one and when ricky gets added the value of i will be 10, so we have to subtract it by 2 to get sara's index.
              }
            }
            if (i == size - 1) {
               System.out.println(value + " value starts from index " + j + " And up to index " + i);

            }
  }

}
```

Output :

> 1. jack value starts from index 0 And up to index 4
> 2. sara value starts from index 6 And up to index 8
> 3. ricky value starts from index 10 And up to index 12

**Note** :- This code will work for the input given in the question and you have to tweak the logic little bit if you want this to work on other arraylist.
I have added comments in the code, even then if you don't understand debug the code as logic is simple.

You can check output [here](http://ideone.com/bev5lT).

Comment: @ Ravikumar . I need to your help.Can you help me ?

Comment: @Rose Okay, what I can help with?

Comment: Please comming in chat room.

Comment: Invite me ,How I can find you ?

Comment: I can't speak with you . web site say me : You must have 20 reputation on Stack Overflow to talk here. See the faq.

Comment: Yeah I know it, I was finding a way to invite people less than 20 reputation but it seems like only moderator can add that.

Comment: You have to ask your question here, there seems no other way.

Comment: Can you come to chat gmail ? my gmail is roser9808@gmail.com .

Comment: Get your email or add me.

Comment: @Rose I am on gmail chat, we will discuss there and remove all unwanted comments.